# Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning DefaultInlineConstraintResolver in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api2

I need to use `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning` in VB.NET but I cannot translate the following code:

```
config.AddApiVersioning(o =>
{
   o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
   o.DefaultApiVersion = new Microsoft.Web.Http.ApiVersion(1, 0);
});

var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver()
{
   ConstraintMap = { ["apiVersion"] = typeof(ApiVersionRouteConstraint) }
};
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);
```

In particular I have an error when I define `DefaultInlineConstraintResolver`:

```
Dim constraintResolver = New DefaultInlineConstraintResolver() With
{
   .ConstraintMap = { ["apiVersion"] = GetType(ApiVersionRouteConstraint) }
}
```

How resolve?
Tks.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. The correct code is:

```
Dim constraintResolver = New DefaultInlineConstraintResolver() 
constraintResolver.ConstraintMap.Add("apiVersion", GetType(ApiVersionRouteConstraint))
```